# Gunicorn connection error on Amazon ec2

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

Hi when I'm connected to my amazon ec2 instance (AMI is amazon linux) via ssh and run the command `gunicorn routes:app --bind 0.0.0.0:80` I get this error message:

```
[2018-02-05 02:49:24 +0000] [3076] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
[2018-02-05 02:49:24 +0000] [3076] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2018-02-05 02:49:25 +0000] [3076] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2018-02-05 02:49:26 +0000] [3076] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2018-02-05 02:49:27 +0000] [3076] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2018-02-05 02:49:28 +0000] [3076] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2018-02-05 02:49:29 +0000] [3076] [ERROR] Can't connect to ('0.0.0.0', 80)
```

I tried seeing if that port was taken by running `sudo netstat -nlp | grep :80` but it returns nothing which means the port isn't being used.

Why isn't gunicorn able to run?

EDIT:
I altered the inbound rules in security group so that its open to all ports then `gunicorn hello:app -b :8080`. Now its running on port 8080. I wonder why it doesn't work on the default port 80

Comment: Are you running `iptables`?

Comment: I don't think so. I just configured the inbound traffic to accept http on port 80 under security groups

Comment: Could you be running an IPv6 stack? If yes the address would be `::/0` not `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: its an IPV4 stack

Comment: I edited my inbound rule to let ALL TRAFFIC come in and then gunicorn hello:app -b :8080 now works on port 8080. I wonder why it doesn't work on http port 80?

Comment: Some OS firewalls block port 80 by default. Maybe you have some other firewall akin to `iptables`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port 80 requires super user privilege. It's recommended to use a reverse proxy such as nginx on port 80 and place gunicorn on another port above 1024